# Como adicionar onClick no botão "Desenhar Forma" do Google Maps Api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Eu gostaria de adicionar o evento "onClick" no "Desenhar Forma" do "Drawing Controller" do google maps api v3.

Não consegui achar na documentação e não tem como clicar com o botão direito no botão para verificar se possui um "id".

Alguém saberia como fazer isto?

Answer (score 0):

Basta você pegar a forma, apontando sua variável.
Por exemplo, digamos que você tenha um ponteiro de localização.
Você chama a variável dele e insere um evento com:

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    //código de ações aqui...
});

Aconselho a você iterar nos pontos ou objetos que você quer ter ações. Cria uma função para isto de cara, pois depois você verá que será necessário em escala maior.

Comment: No caso eu posso fazer o seguinte:

- Verificar o getMode do drawing, Caso o botão clicado do drawing for 'polygon' ele faz algo.
Funciona assim?

Comment: Pode sim, mas precisa achar alguma referência do tipo